# avoiding action when text box is empty

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have my search button as below (selectedPartFilter is a text box)

```
<input type="BUTTON" class="submit" id="searchButton" value="<fmt:message key="search.button"/>" onClick="if (validateFilterCriteria()) JavaScript:submitAction('FILTER_DOCUMENTS');showBusy();" />
```

**validateFilterCriteria** method is as below

```
function validateFilterCriteria() {
    var partFilter = document.getElementById("selectedPartFilter").value;

    if (partFilter != ''){
        document.getElementById("partFilter").value = partFilter;
        return true;
    }
    if (partFilter == '') {
        alert('Please enter part of the part number');
        return false;

    }

}
```

**There is a busy gif displayed using showBusy() method.**

Now irrespective of the return of the validateFilterCriteria(), the busy gif is being displayed. I do not want it to be displayed when there is no value entered in the text box

Comment: Can you show us the code for showBusy()?

Comment: function showBusy() {
 document.getElementById('mask').className = 'visibleDiv';
 
 return false;
 }

Comment: This is just to show a gif saying that page is loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
onClick="if (validateFilterCriteria()) { JavaScript:submitAction('FILTER_DOCUMENTS');showBusy(); }"
```

You should wrap your code within braces.

Answer (score 0):

The initial value for the input element is undefined instead of ''

If you compare

```
undefined == '' //false
```

To make your function work as expected you could simplify it and rewrite it as

```
function validateFilterCriteria() {
    var partFilter = document.getElementById("selectedPartFilter").value;

    //Here we check if the value is truthy instead of comparing it directly with an empty string
    if (partFilter) {
        document.getElementById("partFilter").value = partFilter;
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('Please enter part of the part number');
        return false;

    }
}
```